# In HTML e-mails, what's the alternative to table 'cellpadding'?

Tags: html-email, padding

Since 'cellpadding' attribute is not supported in HTML5, what's the best way to apply padding to all cells in a table in HTML e-mail?

I've read that linked style sheets are are bad idea as widely ignored by email clients so at the moment I can only think of adding inline `style="padding:5px;"` to every element in table but this seems pretty long-winded!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though something isn't supported, emails are a special rule. The bgcolor="" rule for example has been depreciated for a while, yet is still the best way to add a background color in email. In fact, most email clients strip out the doctag all together.

Linked style sheets don't work, even style tags are ignored by web clients.

[Here](http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters-all-new-version/?doing_wp_cron=1346955817.6005339622497558593750) and [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails) and [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/coding/) are some references to get you started in the crazy world of html email design